# Get other's Firebase display name and photo URL from ID in Ionic3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I am using Firebase in my Ionic3 app. I am storing other user's ID as friend data. How can I get the Display name and photo URL for other users from their ID?

Comment: When a user is signed in, you can get the displayName and photoURL from the currentUser: `firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName` and `firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL`

Comment: I am not looking for the current user data. How to get other/friend user data like Name or Photo URL by their user ID?

Comment: can you please share me the code for both ts and html view file for display the displayName in html file adwinmetal110@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

You can't get that from a client API and rightfully so as it would a security/privacy issue. You should use the Firebase Admin SDKs (eg: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data ), they allow you to lookup users by user ID. you get back a UserRecord which contains the displayName and photoURL along with all the user's data.

Comment: Thanks for this information but this is only for admin use it seems. My requirement is as a user I should be able to see my friend list (name and photo) in my app. Now the user ID of my friends are stored for me. How should I fetch their name and photo. Should I loop thrugh all user IDs and get it from their stored data? What should be a good approch to achieve this?

Comment: You have to build the social graph for this. Firebase Auth doesn't provide such a feature. Firebase provides the tools for you to get the data you need. You have the admin SDK which allows you too look up any user by their user ID. You also have real time database where you can maintain the mapping or also save the display name/photo URL associated with the uid. It also depends on your backend server (are you using your own? cloud functions, serverless, etc)

Comment: I am using Firebase. As I said if I have the list of IDs I can either store the user name and photo URL with it under my user node but that is not the proper way to do it. The other way is to take the list and loop through it to get the data from each user's profile but this can cause performance issue.